# AJAX оптимизация сайта

Tags: ajax, php, html

Привет всем.

Есть (будет) сайт, на котором страницы обновляются по средством AJAX. То есть сайт полностью AJAX-ованный и отдельные блоки и самый главный блок носимый контент тоже обновляется AJAX-ом, как ВКонтакте. Все ссылки индексируемые, но возвращают только нужный кусок страницы, а не целиком сайт.

И встал вопрос, как это дела сделать так, чтобы поисковики индексировали нормально? То есть, если бот перейдет по ссылке, то он должен получить целиком сайт (страницу), а не тот самый кусок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гугл(и очень частично яндекс) умеет ходить по яваскриптовым ссылкам. Для всех остальных делайте карту сайта.

Comment: А можно как нить наверняка?

Comment: Наверняка - карта сайта. Причем в ней все страницы собраны на PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Если ссылки будут иметь конструкцию:

```
<a href="?page=2" onclick="myFunction(thisUrl); return false">Страница</a>
// или вызов функции по селектору
```

То думаю что проблем не будет, так как поисковик будет считывать атрибут **href**

Comment: нет ссылка вида:

    <a href="?page">LINK</a>

далее все перехватывается JQuery...

Comment: ну имелось ввиду что сам атрибут href будет присутствовать в ссылке)

Comment: Та там еще зависит от того, что ответит сервер... а сервер-то отвечает только куском страницы, а не целиком...

Comment: Googl'ь сканирует страницу и вносит все найденные ссылки себе в базу, потом из этой базы ходит по ссылкам! Или вы думаете что поисковик попав на ссылку сразу хавает ее и возвращается снова на главную чтобы найти там еще какую нить ссылку?))

Использование AJAX технологий набирает хорошую динамику, и поисковые системы это все учитывают!

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю как работают поисковики. Я говорю "А", а вы понимаете "Б"...

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай, вы ключ прописываете в href или его уже jq добавляет? во втором случае проблем не будет точно.

Comment: Да, ключ добавляю в href. Но до меня доперло, что надо динамически его добавлять

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".my-local-links").click( function (event) {
        //Получу event, где event.target - элемент по которому я клацнул. Исходя из него делай что хочешь :))) 
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
/*...........*/
</head>
<body>
<a href="тра-та-та.com" id="bla-bla-bla" class="my-local-links">Мой ссылк</a>
```

Примерно так....

Comment: Вопрос был не о селекторах.